# "Unexpected token import" angular 2 external module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm using the [ngx-magicsearch](https://github.com/umens/ngx-magicsearch) module in my project with. However, I get the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import.
I am using the version of Angular 4.2.5, Webpack version 1.15.0 and Typescript 2.3.4
Here is my Webpack file:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './app/app.module.ts',
        'vendor': './app/vendor/vendor.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.css', '.html'],
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules", "assets\\js"]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    module: {

        noParse: [/jszip.js$/],

        loaders: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    'angular2-router-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: './app',
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: './app',
                loader: 'raw'
            },
            {
                test: /[\\\/]assets[\\\/]js[\\\/]modernizr\.min\.js$/,
                loader: "imports?this=>window!exports?window.Modernizr"
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            KJUR: "jsrsasign-latest-all-min",
            b64utoutf8: "base64x",
            dateFormat: "dateformat",
            moment: "moment"
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].bundle.css'),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor']
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
};
```

tsconfig.js:

```
    {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "removeComments": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true

    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "buildOnSave": false
}
```

And the errors[image: console]:
[image: app.bundle]

Answer (score 1):

The [entry point of ngx-magicsearch](https://unpkg.com/ngx-magicsearch@2.1.1/index.js) uses ES modules. You would need to transpile them with babel to use it. Usually the packages publish a transpiled version, although many of them now also publish a version with ES modules that can be used by bundling tools that support them. ES modules are supported out of the box, since webpack 2.

It is highly recommended to upgrade webpack. You'll have to adapt your config a little. For details have a look at the [official migration guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/).

Comment: OK.
Is it possible that after the upgrade, the other modules can cause problems?

Comment: No, it should support everything it did before and more, but you need to make sure that you migrated the config correctly.